# what will happen on Azure Functions during maintenance?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I know that Web Apps will be rebooted during maintenance without notice.

But how about the case of Functions?
During maintenance, does the current execution get stopped?

I think it is difficult to retry Timer, Http, Event Hub Triggered Functions.
But I wish Functions runtime will make my code retry after the maintenance finishes.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has several parts, so:

1. Probably yes, Azure will stop routing requests to an instance which is about to get maintenance done. Because Function executions are short-lived (on Consumption Plan), that's relatively easy to do.
2. "Probably" - because this is not something they guarantee to you. Overall, Functions on Consumption Plan have no SLA, and host behavior details might change over time.
3. If stopping in the middle of function execution is a problem for your business case, you still need to handle it. Any instance can experience hardware failure at any time, including the least convenient time possible.
4. The observed behavior in case of such failure will differ per trigger type. E.g. HTTP call will just fail with 5xx code and the client is supposed to retry it. Queue-based triggers have a mechanism with locks, timeouts and retry counts. Event Hub will restart at the last checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but the whole thing about serverless computing is that you **don't have to worry about these things** anymore. So I would trust Microsoft that they won't stop your function during a maintenance. Thats probably one of the reasons why a function can only run for a limit time period.

Comment: That's probably true, but one *might* still need to worry about an instance *crashing* during the execution (obviously, unplanned, and much more rare)